# How to add multiple references to the same text

Tags: discussion, support

I have multiple references for the same text. Is adding references using superscript like the following a good option?

References <sup>[1](https://www.example.com/) [2](https://www.example.org/) [3](https://www.lipsum.com/)</sup>

What should I do?

### *Update 1*

What happens if there are multiple words? How can I enclose multiple words when using superscript? Should I do something like

*multiple references* <sup>[1](https://www.example.com/) [2](https://www.example.org/) [3](https://www.lipsum.com/)</sup>

or,

**multiple references** <sup>[1](https://www.example.com/) [2](https://www.example.org/) [3](https://www.lipsum.com/)</sup>

or, something else?

Comment: That’s fine, the way you”re doing it.

Comment: what happens if there are multiple words. Here I just used the word `references` and added the superscript. What if the word was `multiple references`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard technique for out-of-line references is to use a comma-separated list of superscripted numbers. Those numbers then correspond to a list of references at the end of the post.

For example:

> According to the United Association of Python Programmers<sup>1</sup>, there is a growing sense of disappointment and frustration with the sluggish speed of Python programs. Multiple studies<sup>1, 2, 3, 4, 5</sup> have indicated that applications developed in languages like C, C++, and even Java are significantly faster than their Python counterparts. Ned Nickerson, a famed Python programmer, attributes this effect to the limitations of the commonly-used CPython reference implementation<sup>6</sup>, speculating that active development work on other implementations<sup>7, 8, 9</sup> may make CPython obsolete. There may even be a way<sup>[citation-needed]</sup> to make Python run as fast as C using a radical, new ahead-of-time compiler, but detractors worry that large elements of the Python community would see this as heresy<sup>10</sup>.
>
> ---
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> https://unitedassociationofpythonprogrammers.com</sub>
> <sub><sup>2</sup> https://example.com</sub>
> <sub><sup>3</sup> https://example.org</sub>
> etc.

Check the Markdown source for how I have accomplished this. I'm basically just using HTML superscript (`<sup></sup>`) and subscript (`<sub></sub>`) tags; nothing too fancy, although a bit fiddly to get the formatting right.

Unfortunately, Markdown doesn't have a standard way to represent citations, so you won't get much better than this. I like this format because it results in the nicest possible presentation (in my opinion), with the least friction to the reader and maximum consistency with other media, while also being *relatively* easy to generate.

---

In HTML, freed from the limitations of traditional, static text media, it is arguably better to avoid explicit citations and instead simply use inline hyperlinks. This is what I tend to do most of the time, because it's easier. For example:

> According to the [United Association of Python Programmers](https://unitedassociationofpythonprogrammers.com), there is a growing sense of disappointment and frustration with the [sluggish](https://example.com/1) [speed](https://example.com/2) [of](https://example.com/3) [Python](https://example.com/4) [programs](https://example.com/5). …

The problem with this is, as you mentioned in an edit to your question, it is difficult to include *multiple* references. You'll see people (including me) hacking around this by making each word of a phrase a separate link, as I did in the example above. This is pretty cute, but also quite un-discoverable: it is not very clear that each of those are separate links, unless the reader hovers over them and looks at the tooltip/address bar.

Comment: @Scratte I always seem to misspell those...